# For customers who ordered an identical product previously, show customer names, productid, and total count of ordering the identical product

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve this problem based on W3Schools.com SQL database. So far, I came up with the following which displays the customer names and productid of customers who ordered an identical product previously. I am having a problem with including the total count of ordering the identical product that the customer ordered.

```
select customername, products.productid, productname
from orderdetails, orders, customers, products
where orderdetails.orderid=orders.orderid AND
      orders.customerid=customers.customerid AND
      orderdetails.productid=products.productid
group by customername, products.productid, productname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
order by customername;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the result query for customer. Move it to a subquery and join to itself

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (select customername, products.productid, productname, COUNT(*) as cnt
    from orderdetails, orders, customers, products
    where orderdetails.orderid=orders.orderid AND
          orders.customerid=customers.customerid AND
          orderdetails.productid=products.productid
    group by customername, products.productid, productname
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) c1 
    INNER JOIN 
    (select customername, products.productid, productname, COUNT(*) as cnt
      from orderdetails, orders, customers, products
      where orderdetails.orderid=orders.orderid AND
            orders.customerid=customers.customerid AND
            orderdetails.productid=products.productid
      group by customername, products.productid, productname
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) c2 
    ON c1.productId=c2.productId and c1.productname=c2.productname

order by c1.customername
```